# Limitations of the simple harmonic oscillator?

Tags: physical-chemistry, spectroscopy

I understand that the simple harmonic oscillator can be used to model the behaviour of molecules at low vibrational states. But why does this not work for molecules that are highly vibrationally excited?

Comment: Good question, I await to see what deep analysis the down voters are preparing as a criticism. But essentially it's the theory of small oscillations (e.g.http://www.nhn.ou.edu/~gut/notes/cm/lect_10.pdf) - for any potential energy curve near enough to a minimum it looks like a parabola, and motion in a parabolic PE curve is SHM. However in real systems the PE curve is not truly a parabola, and the larger the amplitude that the oscillations are, the more the motion will deviate from SHM - and this is what you are referring to above. A proper answer needs maths, hence a comment at the moment.

Comment: I second @IanBush's opinion. In the absence of a full answer, I'll add that in the meantime have a Google for a Morse oscillator, which is more illustrative of the excited state PE curve.

Comment: Real molecules dissociate given enough vibrational and rotational energy, a 'harmonic oscillator' molecule can never dissociate as the potential goes to infinity. A Morse oscillator give a more realistic model of a molecule and approximates the HO at low energy. Also experiment shows that energy gaps in real molecules decrease as energy increases, this can never happen in the HO.

Comment: BTW, a simple analogy of deviation from a simple harmonic oscillator is a pendulum. For small amplitude swings, there is a definite period, but as amplitude increases, the period changes -- and once "over the top", there is *no* definite period.